# http // wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

Tags: php

I am working on a multipage website  my directory structure is :
1. controller containing (
    admin,
    public,
    index.php )
2. model containing(
   class,
   config,
   initialize.php )
3. view
4. parameters.php : this is shown below

```
<?php
$dir_root = 'C:/wamp/www/Inceptum/';
$dir_site = 'http://localhost/Inceptum/';
$dir_assets = $dir_site.'view/assets/';
$dir_assets_css = $dir_assets.'css/';
etc.?>
```

i have a file index.php in controller whose code is given below  and my initialize.php
is in model

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once '../../parameters.php';
require_once $dir_model.'initialize.php';
$workshops = Workshop::find_all();
include $dir_public.'home.php';?>
```

This was working on my local server  but when i uploaded it i changeed

```
$dir_root = 'http://www.inceptum.co.in/';$dir_site = 'http://www.inceptum.co.in/';
```

but following error i see

Warning: require_once(../model/initialize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/inceptum/public_html/controller/public/index.php on line 4
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../model/initialize.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/inceptum/public_html/controller/public/index.php on line 4

Comment: your `$dir_root` is the local file path not your `url` you should use something like `$dir_root = basename(__DIR__);`.  If you don't want to set it dynamically use `$dir_root = 'home/inceptum/public_html/';`

Comment: Thanks, That was a great help for me